# PHP - add email into database , send confirmation email and redirect

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm a complete beginner in PHP and having a few difficulties in whats probably very simple. Part of my site will require quick email sign up to access.

To start off with I have a very simple form , here's the HTML:

```
<form>
                <div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
                    <div class="8u">
                        <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="4u">
                        <input name="Submit" type="submit" form value="Submit" action="postemail.php" method="post">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

So it's just a simple form where user can put their email address and a submit button. I'm trying to connect this to postmail.php (I think i've messed up this part: `<input name="Submit" type="submit" form value="Submit" action="postemail.php" method="post">`

Currently it's not connected to postemail.php when you press submit nothing happens.

Here's postmail.php

```
<?php $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); if (!$connection) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("my_database", $connection);
$sql="INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('$_POST[emailaddress]')";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$connection)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_close($connection); 
header('Location: http://www.example.com/STEP1/');?>
```

So hopefully when this works , upon pressing submit the email address will be stored in the database and user redirected to example.com/step1

Finally , which I don't know how to do , I would like the script to also send a confirmation/welcome email to the address. Could I use something like `mail("$_POST[emailaddress]",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");`  to achieve this?

Thank you very much for your time.

(just for reference: Database named my_database , table is Subscribers and column is EmailAddress)

Comment: Please read about `form` and `input` tags and don't mix'em

Comment: Always read the doc for the methods you use. Mysql_* function are deprecated.

Comment: *"I think i've messed up this part"* - Indeed. This `<input name="Submit" type="submit" form value="Submit" action="postemail.php" method="post">` should be `<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit">` then use `<form action="postemail.php" method="post">` on top of that while closing the form tag `</form>`

Comment: However, you have many security holes, such as SQL and XSS injection, do Google those terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first change in your html code

```
   <form action="postemail.php" method="post">
                 <div class="row uniform half collapse-at-2">
                        <div class="8u">
                            <input type="text" name="emailaddress" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="4u">
                            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

then change in your postemail.php

```
<?php 

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass"); 
if (!$connection) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
mysql_select_db("my_database");
$sql="INSERT INTO Subscribers (EmailAddress) VALUES ('$_POST[emailaddress]')";
mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
{
header('Location: http://www.example.com/STEP1/');
}
else{
      echo "fail";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lokesh Jain! The first change is perfect- now that's the form connected to postmail.php. Just the second part still isn't working - keep getting blank page with "fail on it" Everything looks okay in php my admin so don't think its an issue in the DB. Do you have any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: have you added your database username and password in mysql_connect AND database name in mysql_select_db?

Comment: Got it working now - just deleted the database and re-made it and that seemed to fix the problem. Thanks for your help!